# Waitress Nginx Unable to serve static files with relative path

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-wsgi, waitress

I am using waitress as a WSGI to serve my Django application and I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. When I am giving the absolute path to the static files it works fine but if I try to give relative path it doesn't work.

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    access_log "logs/nginx-access.log";
    error_log "logs/nginx-error.log";

    location /static/ {
        alias "C:/Users/mateen/Documents/MDA-Configuration-Server/static/";
        #alias "static/";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8008;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The commented part in location /static/ is what I want to make it work. I have also made sure that the file location is correct. I gave the relative paths in access log and error log and they work fine. Is it something I am missing here?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use a relative path, or why you think it should work. Relative to what?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for looking into this question. I want to use a relative path so that when I deploy the application in production I don't have to change the path every time. In logs what I did is relative path so now its not dependent on my machine but just on my code base. I hope this makes it clear. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I still don't really understand. nginx is for production, there's no reason to use it in development. It's not part of your Django project so you need to tell it where those static files actually are, surely?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I agree with you and so I am trying to tell nginx that the location of static files is in the static folder at the same level as this file is. Just see instead of "C:/Users/mateen/Documents/MDA-Configution-Server/logs/nginx-access.log" I was able to do "logs/nginx-access.log" and that worked. So why when I change "C:/Users/mateen/Documents/MDA-Configuration-Server/static/" to "static/" it does not work. Do you think nginx static files needs the absolute path?